# Unable to authenticate my private channel using redis and socket.io

Tags: php, laravel, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I am using Laravel 5.8 and for broadcasting I use redis, laravel echo server and socket.io not pusher.

I am not using passport either rather a simple session authentication using guards.

What I am trying to do is I want to authenticate a private channel in my application.

Everytime I am getting this error:

`Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 403`

```
[10:56:16 AM] - 6zlHuDCVFNgv_a1OAAAD could not be authenticated to private-public_addresses.12345.1
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\AccessDeniedHttpException",
    "file": "/home/winlappy1/coins_orbit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/RedisBroadcaster.php",
```

A similiar question I came across on stackoverflow is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814177/authentication-issue-with-laravel-private-channel-and-laravel-echo-server) but it does not answer my case.

Here is what I did:

**laravel-echo-server.json**

```
{
    "authHost": "http://localhost:8000",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "123",
            "key": "123"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "127.0.0.1"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "http://localhost:80",
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

**BroadcastServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
         Broadcast::routes();

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

**channel.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('public_addresses.{address}.{purchase_id}', function ($user, $address, $purchase_id) {

    $vendor_id = $user->id;
    if (true == Purchase::findByPublicAddress($address, $vendor_id)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

**Listening to channel in my blade file:**

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

<script src="{{asset('js/echo.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/socket.io.js')}}"></script>

    <script>
        window.Echo = new Echo({
            broadcaster: 'socket.io',
            host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
            auth: {
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            }
        });

        var vendor = Echo.private(`public_addresses.12345.1`);

        vendor.listen("TransactionConfirmed", e => {
            console.log('listened to event successfully');
            console.log(e);
        });
    </script>
```

Here one thing you should note that I am using csrf tokens to authenticate channels, not passport token as I am not using passport.

I have came across many questions but all of them are talking about passport tokens only.

Kindly help me in this regards.

Comment: is this snippet return true "Purchase::findByPublicAddress($address, $vendor_id)" ?

Comment: @sachinkumar yes it is.

Comment: Did you check the Redis log by open redis-server? Means when someone connected then the Redis server log(pub/sub)

Comment: @sachinkumar how to check redis logs ? any command ?

Comment: Redis log or Redis console. When you run Redis on window a process is started which continuously log on their console. Or you can use PUBSUB(https://redis.io/commands)